# SSRS Report runs sometimes

Tags: internet-explorer, ssrs-2008

The Setup:

```
SQL 2008 R2
IIS 7.5 - hosted at RackSpace
1 report
2 sets of data (a,b)
A - 67000 rows of data
B - 15000 rows of data
```

I can run the report on both sets of data without issue.

My client can run the report for set B but not A sometimes.....

```
Y = Yes, every time 
N = No, the report view control shows loading indefinitely
~ = Mixed, 1/4 tries will work.

IE = Internet Explorer
FX = Firefox
GC = Google Chrome
* + SSH = Using an ssh tunnel to my office.

C2B = Client to local dev box. 

      Report with data set A
          | IE | FX | GC | IE + SSH | FX + SSH |
Client    | N  | ~  | ~  | Y        | Y        |
My Office | Y  | Y  | Y  | Y        | Y        |
My house  | Y  | Y  | Y  | Y        | Y        |
C2B       | Y  | Y  | Y  | N/A      | N/A      |

      Report with data set B
          | IE | FX | GC | IE + SSH | FX + SSH |
Client    | Y  | Y  | Y  | Y        | Y        |
My Office | Y  | Y  | Y  | Y        | Y        |
My house  | Y  | Y  | Y  | Y        | Y        |
C2B       | Y  | Y  | Y  | N/A      | N/A      |
```

What am I missing?

-- EDIT --

Using the "Network" tab in the IE developer tools the report makes three http GET requests to the server. When it fails the second request get's stuck in a waiting state indefinitely.

Answer (score 0):

[+1 for providing plenty of data with your question.]

Seems like you've got a pretty clear pointer at the culprit. I'll put money ( only a little ) on network devices on the client network, either proxy or firewall, causing the problem.

The proxy (or firewall) may have time or data limits for http connections, and your large report is causing these to be exceeded. The SSH connection wouldn't be affected, the traffic will have very different characteristics than the http connection to the report server.

Set up some monitoring on a client machine at the client site to see what requests are dying and when. [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/) is a nice answer for this.